# In netty is it possible to get multiple request in same tcp connection?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, nio

In netty is it possible to receive the second request from same tcp client while the first request is in progress.

Below is the sample code which I have tried:

```
public class SomethingServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    String stringMessage = (String) msg;
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug(stringMessage);
    }
    ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    String[] splitMessage = stringMessage.split("::");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if ( splitMessage.length != 2 ) {
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(stringMessage + "\n\r");
        return;
    }
    if ( channelRepository.get(splitMessage[0]) != null ) {
        channelRepository.get(splitMessage[0]).writeAndFlush(splitMessage[1] + "\n\r");
    }       
}
```

From command line:
telnet localhost port

string1

string2

Here on the server side string2 is printed after 10 sec once string1 processing completes. Is there anyway I can process string2 in parallel?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you offload the work to another thread. You are blocking the `EventLoop` which means that no other work can happen on its thread. This will not only affect this connection but all other connections that are handled by the same `EventLoop`.

Comment: My use case is request response model, in between the response user can send another request. If I offload the work to another thread how will I get the response back? Sorry I'm new to netty, exploring whether netty supports this model.

Comment: I guess you can also pass the channel to handler thread and write response through that channel.

Comment: This approach worked. Thanks!!! I was looking within netty to make the handler non blocking. Didn't think of this alternative.

Comment: ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        executor.submit(() -> {
         try {
       Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
            if ( splitMessage.length != 2 ) {
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(stringMessage + "\n\r");
                return;
            }
            if ( channelRepository.get(splitMessage[0]) != null ) {
                channelRepository.get(splitMessage[0]).writeAndFlush(splitMessage[1] + "\n\r");
            }
        });